# Internet Explorer Compatibility Script

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I am running an web application on one of my server, the problem is that Internet Explorer 9 doesn't support the web application. How ever Internet Explorer 8 supports the web application.

Is it possible to write a script, that when a user logs on to their machine, the script is executed that change the compatibility mode of Internet Explorer 9 to Internet Explorer 8 for a specific URL.

I know how to do it manually on the users machine. there are to many machine to do this manually.

Please help, I am not an Server Expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that you modify/change the html output of your web application?
If so, you could think about modifying the web application to enforce IE8 compatibility mode always in IE9 browsers.

Have a look at this:
http://webdesign.about.com/od/internetexplorer/qt/force-compatibility-view-in-ie.htm

Edit:
Ok, no possibility to change the html. Then have a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699448.aspx, Section "Managing Compatibility View with Group Policy". There you can force compatibility mode for certain websites through the group policy. Even if your PC isn't member of a domain you should be able to control these settings through the local group policy settings in control panel.

Another option could be to modify the local internet explorer compatibility list. Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd567845(v=vs.85).aspx
and this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/09/29/ie9-s-faster-more-capable-compatibility-view-list.aspx
But I don't know if this is an good idea because it seems that this list will be replaced/updated by Microsoft automatically. Perhaps you have to ensure on every system logon that your modifications are still present.

Comment: It is a SAP Business Objects application, so no i cannot change the web application.